# Scrolling Layouts with buttons!

Tags: android

I am trying to make a scrollable layout that contains many relativelayouts and button. (See example below). But every time i make a scrollview it says a scroll view can on contain one child...

EXAMPLE

Scrollview

```
Relativelayouts1
    Button1
Relativelayouts2
    Button2
Relativelayouts3
    Button3
Relativelayouts4
    Button4
```

Scrollview (END)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is simple... Wrap the child layouts with a single layout.  For example, something like the following.

```
ScrollView
    LinearLayout
        Relativelayouts1
            Button1
        Relativelayouts2
            Button2
        Relativelayouts3
            Button3
        Relativelayouts4
            Button4
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i can finish what i am doing!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to have 4 RelativeLayouts? It defeats the purpose of that layout. Most probably, you can get the same result using:

```
<ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This way you avoid wasting precious resources generating useless Views.

Take your time to read this post: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/ (and parts 2 and 3 also)

Comment: It is the way the way the buttons are laid out. They are not one on tope of the other. They are in specific groups.

Comment: That is precisely what RelativeLayout is about.